# Enable and disable AUX port

Tags: cisco, router

I'm trying to disable line aux 0 with the following commands on a AS2511-RJ router:

```
conf t
!
line aux 0
 transport input none
 transport output none
 no exec
 exec-timeout 0 1
 no password
!
end
```

Is it the right way and how can I re-enable it if need to?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, I had to go look up the part number and it's actually on a part of Cisco's site where they've archived the picture files...

Second you could shorten your config to:

```
line aux 0
 no exec
```

And to re-enable the config would be:

```
line aux 0
 exec
```

Note you can still use the aux line for reverse telnet access to a serial port on another device with `no exec` configured, so you're only preventing incoming sessions with that command.